# Figuring Out Marginal Density by Looking at Plot of Joint Density

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, density-function, marginal-distribution

I have the below plot of the joint density of X and Y. 
X and Y are continuous random variables. X takes on values between 0 and 2 while Y takes on values between 0 and 1.

Can someone please explain to me how does someone go about getting the marginal density of X simply by looking at the plot of the joints?

The answer to the question is given by the below expression:

$f_{X}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{x / 2,} & {\text { if } 0 \leq x \leq 1} \\ {-3 x / 2+3,} & {\text { if } 1<x \leq 2} \\ {0,} & {\text { otherwise }}\end{array}\right.$

But if someone can please explain how does one arrive at it.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: $$f_X(x) = \int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Sure you use this when you know $f_{X,Y}$, but in the case above I see uniform distributions over joint X,Y in two intervals...

Comment: I added the solution, it's not very intuitive... I hope someone can comment on what one needs to think of in order to arrive at the solution.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, it may help to compute \begin{align}f_X(0.2) &= \int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(0.2, y)dy \\&= \int_{-\infty}^{?} f_{X,Y}(0.2,y)dy + \int_{?}^{?} f_{X,Y}(0.2,y)dy + \int_{?}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(0.2,y)dy \end{align}

Comment: @AAC if you have a uniform density in each of the regions as indicated, then $$f_{\small X,Y}(x,y) =\begin{cases} 1/2 &:& x\in[0,1), y\in[0,x]\\3/2 &:& x\in[1,2], y\in [0,2-x]\\0&:& \text{else}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ depends on two variables you have to imagine the function as two plateaus with height $1/2$ and $3/2$ above the corresponding triangles, and zero everywhere else (which I didn't plot):

[image]

Now, in order to compute the marginal
$$
f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, \mathrm dy
$$
you have to imagine (the area of) the cross sections for every $x$ separately (I plotted two possible choices of $x$):

[image]

If you know what to do, you can also perform these steps in your head by looking at your original drawing:

[image]

What is left is to figure out for each $x$ the corresponding height $\ell$ and take the area of the crossection, which is $\ell\cdot \frac{1}{2}$ for $x\le 1$ and $\ell\cdot \frac{3}{2}$ for $x>1$. This gives you your answer.

Comment: perfect answer, thank you

Comment: Hello @iljusch , with the same spirit would you mind please helping understand why answer to the question 
what is $f_{X | Y}(x | 0.5)$ the below?



$f_{X | Y}(x | 0.5)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{1 / 2,} & {\text { if } 1 / 2 \leq x \leq 1} \\ {3 / 2,} & {\text { if } 1<x \leq 3 / 2} \\ {0,} & {\text { otherwise }}\end{array}\right.$

Comment: By definition of conditional probability densities you have $f_{X|Y}(x|0.5)\propto f_{X,Y}(x,0.5)$, so you just need to take the cross section of the joint density, but this time in $x$-direction for $y=0.5$ (I am sure you can do this by looking at the top picture) and then normalize (such that it becomes a probability density). After the first step you get the result you wrote down, and in this particular case (by "coincidence"), it is already normalized, so you are finished.

Comment: thanks a lot, really appreciate it... Understood what you are saying and was able to get to the answers as you described